# Remove a particular section from {{ content_for_layout }} in shopify template

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am trying to customize **Supply** theme in shopify In **theme.liquid**  file and  i can see {{ content_for_layout }} which loads slider, featured collection etc.Now I want to remove slider from that section.Can anyone suggest which file I should check ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find for setting_data.json there you can find all declared values. There you can search for "content_for_index".